# How to count number of non empty lines in a file using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

how to find how many lines I have in file by sed
(need to ignore spaces and empty lines)

for example

if I have file with 139 lines (line can include only one character)
then sed should return 139

lidia

Comment: [This page](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/sedoneliner.shtml) says to do: `sed -n '$='`

Comment: @Seth: That is just `wc -l` which does not ignore blank lines as OP wants.

Comment: @codaddict - I would `wc -l` myself; I'm not a sed guy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a job for `grep`, not `sed`:

```
<myfile grep -c '[^[:space:]]'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
sed -n '/[^[:space:]]/p' filename | wc -l
```

Here `sed` prints only those line that have at least one non-space char and `wc` counts those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use nawk instead of sed.

```
nawk 'NF{c++}END{print "total: "c}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^ *$/ d' filename | wc -l
```

Here, `sed` prints the lines after deleting all the lines with 0 or more spaces from beginning to the end. `wc -l` is to count the number of these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '$count++ if /\S/; END { print int $count }' input.file
```